# Node Login Error: Cannot GET /users/auth/login

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, model-view-controller, controller

i am getting this error while trying to login on my Node Applications:

Cannot GET /users/auth/login

after setting my view, controller and routes appropriately.

please help guys>

```
see my controller file below

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const User = require('../database/models/User')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    //try to find user
    User.findOne({ email }, (error, user) => {
        if (user) {
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, same) => {
            if (same) {
                res.redirect('/')
            } else {
                res.redirect('auth/login')
                }
            })
        } else {
            return res.redirect('/auth/login')
        }
    })

};
```

and my Html below

```
<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
              <form action="/users/login" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="control-group">
```

likewise my route:

```
const loginUserController = require('./controllers/loginUser')
app.get("/auth/login", loginController);
app.post("/users/login", loginUserController);
```

and i still get this as my output when this login button is clicked>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpspW.png)

and i don't know what i am still getting wrong as i am not supposed to be getting that callback link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful while using res.redirect you had put auth/login instead of /auth/login

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const User = require("../database/models/User");

module.exports = (req, res) => {
const { email, password } = req.body;
//try to find user
User.findOne({ email }, (error, user) => {
    if (user) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, same) => {
        if (same) {
        res.redirect("/");
        } else {
        res.redirect("/auth/login");
        }
    });
    } else {
    return res.redirect("/auth/login");
    }
});
};
```

This should fix your problem, let me know if any problems